# Camerax how to disable auto-focus

Tags: java, android, autofocus, android-camerax

I develop an android app to scan QR code by camerax. how to disable auto focus when preview?

no tried

```
public void initCamera(Fragment fragment, OnQRResultListener onQRResultListener) {
    mOnQRResultListener = onQRResultListener;
    PreviewConfig previewBuild = new PreviewConfig.Builder()
            .setTargetResolution(new Size(getWidth(), getHeight()))
            .setTargetAspectRatio(new Rational(1, 1))
            .setLensFacing(CameraX.LensFacing.FRONT)
            .build();
    preview = new Preview(previewBuild);
    preview.setOnPreviewOutputUpdateListener(new Preview.OnPreviewOutputUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onUpdated(Preview.PreviewOutput output) {
            textureView.setSurfaceTexture(output.getSurfaceTexture());
        }
    });
    HandlerThread analyzerThread = new HandlerThread("BarcodeAnalyzer");
    analyzerThread.start();
    ImageAnalysisConfig analysisBuild = new ImageAnalysisConfig.Builder()
            .setTargetResolution(new Size(getWidth(), getHeight()))
            .setTargetAspectRatio(new Rational(1, 1))
            .setLensFacing(CameraX.LensFacing.FRONT)
            .setImageReaderMode(ImageAnalysis.ImageReaderMode.ACQUIRE_LATEST_IMAGE)
            .setCallbackHandler(new Handler(analyzerThread.getLooper()))
            .build();
    ImageAnalysis analysis = new ImageAnalysis(analysisBuild);
    analysis.setAnalyzer(new QRCodeAnalyzer(onAnalyzerResultListener));
    CameraX.bindToLifecycle(fragment, preview, analysis);
}
```

it scan qr result slowly

Comment: Try with preview.focus() method, with full area of your view as a rectangle parameter.

Answer (score 0):

See this link:

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/FocusMeteringAction.Builder#disableAutoCancel()

Also see this answer on stackoverflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60095886/8401205

This is a simple java version of little code segment:

`FocusMeteringAction action = new FocusMeteringAction.Builder(point,                    FocusMeteringAction.FLAG_AF).disableAutoCancel().build();`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cancelFocusAndMetering()`

```
val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)
    cameraProviderFuture.addListener(Runnable {
        // Used to bind the lifecycle of cameras to the lifecycle owner
        val cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()
...
        // Bind use cases to camera
        val camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this, cameraSelector, preview, imageCapture)

        camera.cameraControl.cancelFocusAndMetering()
}
```