# How to auto-focus with Android CameraX

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-camerax

Android has released a new API camerax in recent months.  I'm trying to understand how to get auto-focusing for the camera to work.

https://groups.google.com/a/android.com/forum/#!searchin/camerax-developers/auto$20focus|sort:date/camerax-developers/IQ3KZd8iOIY/LIbrRIqEBgAJ

Here is a discussion on the topic but there is almost no specific documentation on it.

https://github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/master/CameraXBasic/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/cameraxbasic

Here is also the basic camerax app but I couldn't find any file dealing with the auto  focusing.

Any tips or points to  documentation is  helpful.  Also I'm fairly new to android so its  very possible I'm missing something that makes the above links more useful.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

With the current CameraX `1.0.0`, you can proceed in this 2 ways:

1. Auto-focus every X seconds:

   ```
    previewView.afterMeasured {
        val autoFocusPoint = SurfaceOrientedMeteringPointFactory(1f, 1f)
                .createPoint(.5f, .5f)
        try {
            val autoFocusAction = FocusMeteringAction.Builder(
                autoFocusPoint,
                FocusMeteringAction.FLAG_AF
            ).apply {
                //start auto-focusing after 2 seconds
                setAutoCancelDuration(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            }.build()
            camera.cameraControl.startFocusAndMetering(autoFocusAction)
        } catch (e: CameraInfoUnavailableException) {
            Log.d("ERROR", "cannot access camera", e)
        }
    }
   ```
2. Focus on-tap:

   ```
    previewView.afterMeasured {
        previewView.setOnTouchListener { _, event ->
            return@setOnTouchListener when (event.action) {
                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                    true
                }
                MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                    val factory: MeteringPointFactory = SurfaceOrientedMeteringPointFactory(
                        previewView.width.toFloat(), previewView.height.toFloat()
                    )
                    val autoFocusPoint = factory.createPoint(event.x, event.y)
                    try {
                        camera.cameraControl.startFocusAndMetering(
                            FocusMeteringAction.Builder(
                                autoFocusPoint,
                                FocusMeteringAction.FLAG_AF
                            ).apply {
                                //focus only when the user tap the preview
                                disableAutoCancel()
                            }.build()
                        )
                    } catch (e: CameraInfoUnavailableException) {
                        Log.d("ERROR", "cannot access camera", e)
                    }
                    true
                }
                else -> false // Unhandled event.
            }
        }
    }
   ```

**afterMeasured** extension function is a simple utility: (thanks ch271828n for [improving it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70304116/2910520))

```
inline fun View.afterMeasured(crossinline block: () -> Unit) {
    if (measuredWidth > 0 && measuredHeight > 0) {
        block()
    } else {
        viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.GlobalLayoutListener {
            override fun onGlobalLayout() {
                if (measuredWidth > 0 && measuredHeight > 0) {
                    viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
                    block()
                } 
            }
        })
    }
}
```

A `Camera` object can be obtained with

```
val camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
    this@Activity, cameraSelector, previewView //this is a PreviewView
)
```

Comment: could you giveme the first solution in java?

Comment: For some reason, this code work well on most devices, but some others just refuse to change focus and I can't find why.

Comment: If you think this is a bug, you can open an issue in the android issue tracker of CameraX

Comment: Hi could you please explain the first segment of code? I do not quite understand why it will auto-focus on *every* X seconds, instead of only focusing once

Comment: because we use `setAutoCancelDuration(X, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` which every X seconds cancel the current focus action and restart it (at least this is what I understood from the documentation).
If you replace setAutoCancel with `disableAutoCancel()`, the camera will focus when opened and then will never adjust focus again

Comment: As far as I can see on my device with CameraX of 1.1.0-alpha01 and artifacts of 1.0.0-alpha21 `setAutoCancelDuration` method described in the first way doesn't perform auto-focus every n seconds. Instead `camera.cameraControl.startFocusAndMetering` initiates focus adjusting according to the provided metering point (`autoFocusPoint`) and keeps this configuration for duration set in `setAutoCancelDuration`. After this duration passed, it restores usual automatic focusing (without any fixed time intervals).

Comment: Moreover, according to the documentation for `SurfaceOrientedMeteringPointFactory`'s constructor, you can use normalized coordinates, i.e. having max values equal to 1.0. In such simple case when we want to adjust a focus according to the central point, we can prepare our metering point even simpler (without `PreviewView`): `val autoFocusPoint = SurfaceOrientedMeteringPointFactory(1f, 1f).createPoint(.5f, .5f)`

Comment: @AndreiK. I've done some tests and I've updated the auto-focus sample on using your proposed `autoFocusPoint` which is cleaner. I've tested the cancel thing and based on my tests if I remove `setAutoCancelDuration` the first time the camera is open it will wait the default 5 seconds before starting to auto-focus (which for me is too much time) so I prefer to leave the 2 seconds there. After the first time, the auto-focus timing is decided by the camerax library (which is near to real-time in my device). BTW thank you for your research

Comment: Hi, I would like to know why not to use always the preview width and height instead of 1F? what it does if I put 1F? thank you :)

Comment: @ladytoky0 you can find info [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/SurfaceOrientedMeteringPointFactory#SurfaceOrientedMeteringPointFactory(float,%20float)) if you use 1f you use "normalized" coordinate system, where 1f means available width/height

Comment: Hi, the `afterMeasured` has a bug: frequently its callback is never called. Here is a fix: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70304116/4619958

Comment: @ch271828n answer updated, thank you

Comment: can we have this code variant in java

Comment: Nice Example,thanks! Is it possible to install kind of a callback, where you get the information if the Autofocus was able to adjust a sharp image in the image stream? I would like to pass the content only then to a 3rd party library for processing the image.

Answer (score 5):

Just point out, to get the "Tap to focus" working with PreviewView, you need to use
*DisplayOrientedMeteringPointFactory*. Otherwise you'll get messed up coordinates.

```
val factory = DisplayOrientedMeteringPointFactory(activity.display, camera.cameraInfo, previewView.width.toFloat(), previewView.height.toFloat())
```

For the rest use the MatPag's answer.

Answer (score 3):

There is an issue with some android devices where the camera's aren't auto-focusing with CameraX.  The CameraX team is aware of it and are tracking it with an internal  ticket and hopefully will have a fix soon.

Comment: I've added an answer to this

Comment: Is there a public link for this ticket?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the doc here about Focus as it was added in "1.0.0-alpha05"
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/camera#camera2-core-1.0.0-alpha05

Basically you have to set a touch listener on your view and grab the clicked position

```html
private boolean onTouchToFocus(View viewA, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    return focus(event);
                break;
            default:
                // Unhandled event.
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

And translate this position into point

```html
private boolean focus(MotionEvent event) {
        final float x = (event != null) ? event.getX() : getView().getX() + getView().getWidth() / 2f;
        final float y = (event != null) ? event.getY() : getView().getY() + getView().getHeight() / 2f;

        TextureViewMeteringPointFactory pointFactory = new TextureViewMeteringPointFactory(textureView);
        float afPointWidth = 1.0f / 6.0f;  // 1/6 total area
        float aePointWidth = afPointWidth * 1.5f;
        MeteringPoint afPoint = pointFactory.createPoint(x, y, afPointWidth, 1.0f);
        MeteringPoint aePoint = pointFactory.createPoint(x, y, aePointWidth, 1.0f);

           try {
            CameraX.getCameraControl(lensFacing).startFocusAndMetering(
                FocusMeteringAction.Builder.from(afPoint, FocusMeteringAction.MeteringMode.AF_ONLY)
                                           .addPoint(aePoint, FocusMeteringAction.MeteringMode.AE_ONLY)
                                           .build());
        } catch (CameraInfoUnavailableException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "cannot access camera", e);
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: I added an answer to the question.  Touch to focus isn't auto-focus.

Answer (score 1):

With current `1.0.0-rc03` and `1.0.0-alpha22` artifacts

This solution assumes that camera is already setup including `bindToLifecycle`. After that we need to check whether previewView streamState is STREAMING before trying to focus the camera

```
 previewView.getPreviewStreamState().observe(getActivity(), value -> {
        if (value.equals(STREAMING)) {
            setUpCameraAutoFocus();
        }
    });

private void setUpCameraAutoFocus() {
    final float x =  previewView.getX() + previewView.getWidth() / 2f;
    final float y =  previewView.getY() + previewView.getHeight() / 2f;

  MeteringPointFactory pointFactory = previewView.getMeteringPointFactory();
  float afPointWidth = 1.0f / 6.0f;  // 1/6 total area
  float aePointWidth = afPointWidth * 1.5f;
  MeteringPoint afPoint = pointFactory.createPoint(x, y, afPointWidth);
  MeteringPoint aePoint = pointFactory.createPoint(x, y, aePointWidth);
  ListenableFuture<FocusMeteringResult> future = cameraControl.startFocusAndMetering(
          new FocusMeteringAction.Builder(afPoint,
                  FocusMeteringAction.FLAG_AF).addPoint(aePoint,
                  FocusMeteringAction.FLAG_AE).build());
  Futures.addCallback(future, new FutureCallback<FocusMeteringResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(@Nullable FocusMeteringResult result) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
      // Throw the unexpected error.
      throw new RuntimeException(t);
    }
  }, CameraXExecutors.directExecutor());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `afterMeasured` function in [highest voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60095886/4619958) has a serious bug: **Frequently its callback is *never* called**.

The very simple fix:

```
inline fun View.afterMeasured(crossinline block: () -> Unit) {
    if (measuredWidth > 0 && measuredHeight > 0) {
        block()
    } else {
        viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
            override fun onGlobalLayout() {
                if (measuredWidth > 0 && measuredHeight > 0) {
                    viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
                    block()
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Explanation: I have observed (in an app in production) that, sometimes the view is already measured and no ui changes so `onGlobalLayout` will never be called later. Then the `afterMeasured`'s callback will never be called, so the camera is not initialized.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and I set up this solution (even if it looks pretty dumb).

```
val displayMetrics = resources.displayMetrics
val factory = SurfaceOrientedMeteringPointFactory(
    displayMetrics.widthPixels.toFloat(),
    displayMetrics.heightPixels.toFloat()
)
val point = factory.createPoint(
    displayMetrics.widthPixels / 2f,
    displayMetrics.heightPixels / 2f
)
val action = FocusMeteringAction
            .Builder(point, FocusMeteringAction.FLAG_AF)
            .build()

try {
    camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
        lifecycleOwner,
        cameraSelector,
        preview,
        imageAnalyzer
    )
    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
        while (workflowModel.isCameraLive) {
            camera?.cameraControl?.startFocusAndMetering(action)?
            delay(3000)
        }
    }
} catch (e: Exception) {
    Log.e(mTag, "Use case binding failed", e)
}
```

Basically, I restart the focusing action every 3s in a `while` loop.

`isCameraLive` is a boolean variable I store in my viewModel and I set `true` when I start the camera and `false` when I stop it by calling `cameraProvider.unbindAll()`.